# Simplifying $\frac{a^3 +ab + a^2 -b}{a^3 +ab +a^2 +b}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For context, this is high school algebra and I'm trying to simplify this fraction:

$$\frac{a^3 +ab + a^2 -b}{a^3 +ab +a^2 +b}$$

My textbook says that the simplified answer is:

$$\frac{a^3 +ab + a^2 -b}{(a^2+b)(a+1)}$$

BUT, I thought I could simplify to:

$$\frac{(a^2-b)(a+1)}{(a^2+b)(a+1)}$$

Why is it correct to simplify the denominator this way, but not the numerator?

Thank you.

Comment: Depends on your goal.  The expression $=1-\frac{2b}{a^3+ab+a^2+b}$.

Comment: what have tou tried?

Comment: I edited the post, realized my question was misleading.

Comment: the numerator $(a^2-b)(a+1)$ is $a^3\color{red}{-}ab+a^2-b$ which is not the numerator

Comment: After distributing the two binominals (a^2-b)(a+1), I can see that the result is different and that my intuition was wrong. Are there any rules or any trick that I'm missing so it would be possible to quickly identify if the numerator can be simplified?

Answer (score 1):

@Jay - as others have said in the comments, your factorisation wasn't right. You ask whether there any rules or any trick that you're. Here are a couple:

If $(a-1)$ is a factor of an expression then setting $a=1$ will make it zero. So put $a=1$ into the original expression and see what you get. Similarly, if $(a^2-b)$ is a factor of an expression then setting $a^2=b$ will make it zero.

If you expand out two binomials with all positive signs, you will get 4 terms and they will all be positive:
$$(p+q)(r+s)=pr+ps+qr+qs$$

Similarly, If you expand out two binomials and there is one minus sign, you will get 4 terms and two will be negative:
$$(p+q)(r-s)=pr-ps+qr-qs$$

You can see that it's hard to get exactly one minus sign from this sort of exercise.

Depending on the complexity of what you are looking at, some terms may cancel or combine. The classic is:
$$(p-q)(p+q)=p^2+pq-pq-q^2=p^2-q^2$$
But there is also, for example:
$$(p-q)(p^2+pq+q^2)=p^3-q^3$$
In the last example note that there are $2 \times 3 = 6$ terms but 4 of them cancel. Both sides are zero when $p=q$.

Comment: if $(a-1)$ is a factor then setting $a=\color{red}{1}$....

Comment: @IITM - thanks - fixed

Comment: This answer was very helpful, thank you. Unfortunately, I do not have enough reputation points to give you an upvote.

Comment: No problem @Jay. I gave you an upvote to help you on you way!